# Python design advice

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have written a generic framework in python for some particular type of task. It is a webserver which serves different requests and operations. This framework can be used by many projects and each one has a different set of validation rules. Right now, I'm just updating my script for each project.

I'm thinking of externalizing this validation part, how do I go about this? The validations are more than mere field content validations; I'm thinking of having a config file which maps `incoming request <-> validationModule` something like `/site1/a/b.xml=validateSite1.py` and importing this module in an if condition if the request is for `site1`. So I'll have generic framework scripts + individual scripts for each site.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'd be better to use Python itself as the top-level mapping from URL paths to validation modules.  A configuration might look like this:

```
import site1
import site2
def dispatch(uri):
    if uri.startswith('/site1/'):
        return site1.validate(uri)
    elif uri.startswith('/site2/):
        return site2.validate(uri)
```

This simple example might tempt you to "abstract" it out into a more "generic framework" that turns strings into filenames to use as validation scripts.  Here are some advantages of the doing the above instead:

1. Performance: site modules are imported just once, we don't look up filenames per request.
2. Flexibility: if you decide later that the dispatching logic is more complicated, you can easily use arbitrary Python code to deal with it.  There will never be a need to extend your mapping system itself--only the config files that require more complexity.
3. Single language.

Comment: Yes, this method has a lot of flexibility; only hitch I feel is that the number of import modules will keep on increasing, the imports need to be tracked, remove obsolete ones in the future etc